# view below and overlays another view in android

Tags: android, xml

i want to make a view that will be below another view and overlays it too

i made the following

```
  <RelativeLayout  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">


        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" android:id="@+id/tool"
            />


        <include layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tool"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
         />



        </RelativeLayout>
```

but it didn't work, any solutions?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Why do you need one `View` in from of another ?

Comment: i don't want the view hides the other , but i want to overlay a small part of it only, the design requires this.

Comment: Show us the design then

Comment: The photo in this link describes what i want 
[link](https://ibb.co/k9avwF)

Comment: Add the picture to your post so that people can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to reverse the order of the views, `toolbar` should hide `content_main` so it should be added after it.

Second, you can use negative margins for this, you tell `content_main` to be below `toolbar`, and then put a negative top margin on it, so it moves a bit higher, and beneath `toolbar`.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000" >
    <TextView
        android:text="first line, will be partially covered. fdjkfsjdf kldsjfkdsljfklds "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:text="TOOLBAR" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And result:

[image: Result screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a FrameLayout, instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: I don't understand how can this help at all